# Write a hibernate program to perform crud operations using query interface

Tags: hibernate, hql, crud, hibernate-mapping

Any crud operation related operation must be performed in the maven project and by using hql queries. This crud operation should be performed under query interface
I tried many to many mapping but getting difficulties and errors